# How do I start Far Manager from PowerShell?

Tags: windows, windows-10, powershell, far-manager

Just wondering the above. I installed the program using the .msi GUI installer, with the Path feature selected. I then restarted Windows terminal to pick up the new PATH variables.

Googling shows people using the `far` command, but when I try that I get an error message:

```
> far
far: The term 'far' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Check your PATH environmental variable.

Comment: specify the full path to the command

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to launch the executable directly from the directory containing it, e.g. `> far.exe`

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR** Use the [Start-Process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process?view=powershell-7.4) cmdlet, but a new window will be created.

```
PS C:\> Start-Process far
# or shorter:
PS C:\> start far
```

---

The command starts Far Manager in a new window (unfortunately)
`start  far -NoNewWindow` doesn't work. Is it a bug in PowerShell maybe? (*The system cannot find the file specified*)

> with the Path feature selected

---

**`App paths` vs `PATH`**

The path of Far Manager (`C:\Program Files\Far Manager`) is added only to the registered [app paths](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/app-registration), not to the environment variable `PATH`. This has the implication that cmd/PowerShell won't find the executable directly. An application would have to use [ShellExecuteA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shellexecuteexa) function to automatically find the executable.

---

**How to start far in the same window**

I use Far Manager so often that the shortcut is always pinned to taskbar, and I normally start that directly, not from `cmd` (or PowerShell).
If you want to start Far Manager easier, I would add the Far Manager path (e.g. `C:\Program Files\Far Manager`) to the `PATH` environment variable manually, once. After that you can just execute `far` (from PowerShell or cmd).

```
PS C:\> far
```

Note: For me the background color changes when I start far directly from PS, I don't know why and I don't have a solution:

[image]

---

**cmd.exe**

For completion, for `cmd` (as opposed to PowerShell) you'd have to start the program like this if the folder path isn't added to `PATH`:

```
# starts application in a new window
c:\> start far

# same window is used
c:\> start /b /wait far
```